# How to use a string from another file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, file, uitableview

I have a variable string in one file, but I need to use it in another. It is a bakery application, and it needs to take orders. There is a tableview in the `MasterViewController` and the bakery needs to know what was tapped in the first place. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

#### MasterViewController

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController"bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.item = [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    NSString *selectedItem = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

#### OrderViewController

```
-(IBAction)orderButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    int whereString = [wherePicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSString *mobileString = [mobileField text];
    int amountNumber = [amountPicker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    NSString *specialString = [specialField text];
    NSString *itemString = /*get the string from file here*/
    NSString *orderString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"I would like %d %@ delivered to %@. My mobile number is %@. %@", amountNumber, itemString, whereString, mobileString, specialString];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in `OrderViewController` and then assign the value to the property in master view controller. I hope you know how to create a property, and you can assign the value to the property inside your event...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *__strong)indexPath {
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController"bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.item = [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedItem = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Here you need to assign the value to the property
    detailViewController.theItemString = selectedItem;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give you the maximum number of +'s i can when i have 15 reputation